# Angular8 - object returned from service, sort and display

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dictionary, observable

I am using Angular8. I execute a query that returns a data object. I would like to sort the data object by the `order` value, and then display each item (`product`) of that data object on the browser.

e.g. browser output:

```
  name     description      status            id               order
=====================================================================
drivers                   validated    5rI6n3O2T2z3uKLqbEGj       1
zombies       active      validated    e6T8tOrbUQH1qyo2ECfj       2
passengers                validated    tP4SkWIYRubHN6mCZRA5       3                
lions                     validated    yXfhYcDpzYmyWGYptNme       4
```

The service:

```
public executeQuery(type: string, url: string, id: number, data: any): Observable<any> {
  if ('GET' === type) {
    return this.http.get<any>(url)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.errorHandl)
    )
  } else if ('PUT' === type) {
      return this.http.put<any>(url + id, JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.errorHandl)
      )
    } else if ('POST' === type) {
    return this.http.post<any>(url, JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.errorHandl)
    )
  }
}
```

Raw JSON returned from service call:

```
{
    "products": {
        "drivers": {
            "status": "validated",
            "name": "drivers",
            "description": "",
            "id": "5rI6n3O2T2z3uKLqbEGj",
            "order": 1
        },
        "zombies": {
            "status": "validated",
            "name": "zombies",
            "description": "active",
            "id": "e6T8tOrbUQH1qyo2ECfj",
            "order": 2
        },
        "passengers": {
            "status": "validated",
            "name": "passengers",
            "description": "",
            "id": "tP4SkWIYRubHN6mCZRA5",
            "order": 3
        },
        "lions": {
            "status": "validated",
            "name": "lions",
            "description": "",
            "id": "yXfhYcDpzYmyWGYptNme",
            "order": 4
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see below, I try convert the `data` into a Map, and sort the Map on `order`.

code:

```
this._productService.executeQuery('GET', URL, null, null).subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);   // <== line 31
  console.log(Object.entries(data));
  const dataMap = new Map(data);   // <== line 33
  console.log(dataMap);
  const sortedDataMap = new Map([...dataMap.entries()].sort((a, b) => {
    console.log(a[1], b[1]);
    return 0;//a[1].order - b[1].order;
  }));  

  console.log(sortedDataMap);
  this.data = data;
});
```

console log (from `console.log(data)` on line 31):

```
{products: {…}}
products:
drivers: {name: "drivers", description: "", status: "validated", id: "5rI6n3O2T2z3uKLqbEGj", order: 1}
lions: {status: "validated", name: "lions", description: "", id: "yXfhYcDpzYmyWGYptNme", order: 4}
passengers: {status: "validated", name: "passengers", description: "", id: "tP4SkWIYRubHN6mCZRA5", order: 3}
zombies: {name: "zombies", description: "active", status: "validated", id: "e6T8tOrbUQH1qyo2ECfj", order: 2}
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

html code:

```
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of data">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

error:

```
ERROR TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at new Map (<anonymous>)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (products.component.ts:33)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at CatchSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at CatchSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at RetrySubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at RetrySubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

Question

I am a little confused on how I can order the items, and display them on the browser. If possible, I would like to do this in a generic way, without having to have to refer to the items names explicitly (i.e. use the key for the header item and the value for the rows).

Appreciate any advise.

Comment: that is because `data` is an `Object ` you need an array to iterate in *ngFor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fundamental problem in what you are trying to do. The Map object that you prepare is not iterable as it is a key-value pair object.

What you would need to do here is to convert the JSON in an array of JSONs.

Below are the steps:

```
var x = {
    "products": {
        "drivers": {
            "status": "validated",
            "name": "drivers",
            "description": "",
            "id": "5rI6n3O2T2z3uKLqbEGj",
            "order": 3
        },
        "zombies": {
            "status": "validated",
            "name": "zombies",
            "description": "active",
            "id": "e6T8tOrbUQH1qyo2ECfj",
            "order": 1
        },
        "passengers": {
            "status": "validated",
            "name": "passengers",
            "description": "",
            "id": "tP4SkWIYRubHN6mCZRA5",
            "order": 2
        },
        "lions": {
            "status": "validated",
            "name": "lions",
            "description": "",
            "id": "yXfhYcDpzYmyWGYptNme",
            "order": 4
        }
    }
}
```

Declare the variable. Next, convert it into array using below code.

```
Object.keys(x.products).map(key=>x.products[key])
```

The output of above code is as shown below:

```
0: {status: "validated", name: "drivers", description: "", id: "5rI6n3O2T2z3uKLqbEGj", order: 3}
1: {status: "validated", name: "zombies", description: "active", id: "e6T8tOrbUQH1qyo2ECfj", order: 1}
2: {status: "validated", name: "passengers", description: "", id: "tP4SkWIYRubHN6mCZRA5", order: 2}
3: {status: "validated", name: "lions", description: "", id: "yXfhYcDpzYmyWGYptNme", order: 4}
```

The only steps remaining now is to sort them. Modify the above statement to include sorting:

```
Object.keys(x.products).map(key=>x.products[key]).sort((a,b)=>a.order-b.order)
```

Finally, the value returned from above statement is an iterable array. You can assign that to a variable and iterable it in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Or you may avoid map function also -

```
Object.values(x.products).sort((a,b)=>b.order-a.order)
```